# New to JQuery - Can't get a slider to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm new to JQuery and want to use it to display a simple volume slider.

Can someone please point out my mistake?

Below is a minimal test code. In case it matters, I'm using the JQuery v1.4.1 that comes with MVC2

Sample code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
        Multimedia
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#volume").slider({
                orientation: "vertical",
                range: "min",
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                step: 5,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    //do something;
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="volume"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error: $("#volume").slider is not a function
Source File: file:///c:/sample.html
Line: 15
```

It's worth noting that I can set the contents of `#volume` using .html and similar technique so it *can* find the element - just not the `slider()` function

I'm testing in FF 3.6

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery UI JS file.

Go to the [downloads](http://jqueryui.com/download) page and deselect everything, then select the slider. Doing that will also automatically select the sliders dependencies. You can also choose a theme if you want.